# Getting MethodNotAllowedException using laravel 5

Tags: php, html, rest, laravel-5

Hi I'm new to Laravel and im following the laracasts on view partials and form reuse.

I am getting to an edit page fine. The html looks like this:

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
<h1>Edit: {!! $edu_content->title !!} </h1>

{!! Form::model($edu_content, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'url' => 'edu_contents/' . $edu_content->id ]) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('tags', 'Tags:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('tags', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('user_id', 'User ID:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('user_id', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('location', 'Location:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('location', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('file_size', 'File Size:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('file_size', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('uploaded_at', 'Created On:') !!}
    {!! Form::input('date','uploaded_at', date('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Add Edu content!', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}

</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}

@if ($errors->any())
<ul class="alert alert-danger">
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach

</ul>
@endif

@stop
```

When I view the page source, however, it says `action="http://localhost/edu_contents"` rather than `action="http://localhost/edu_contents/5"` like it should.

Then when I submit the form to update I get:

```
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:
 in RouteCollection.php line 201
 at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 188
 at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD', 'POST')) in RouteCollection.php line 140
 at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 744
 at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
 at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
 at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 229
 at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
 at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
 at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
 at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 54
```

Can anyone explain the error and why the id does not show up in the action?

My routes looks like `Route::resource('edu_contents','EduContentsController');`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the way to make the action. Try this one (change the **update** method with your own):

```
'action' => ['EduContentsController@update', $edu_content->id
```

instead of:

```
'url' => 'edu_contents/' . $edu_content->id
```

Comment: this one $edu_content->title can print the title? if yes, that one: $edu_content->id what can print out?

Comment: Did you try using POST instead of PATCH, check laravel documentation http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#form-method-spoofing, HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions

Comment: @narendra i've been following the laracasts that's what they recommend doing.

Comment: @Panagiotis when I have it be $edu_content->id then this gets printed: `action="http://localhost/edu_contents/5/edit"`. Its strange

Comment: did you install the HTML and Form Builders for the Laravel https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html